# want to add different header file to custom template

Tags: wordpress, templates

I want to add different header file to custom wordpress page template. 
I created a new template for custom post type. I want to add a header file to it using get_header() function, but do not want to use the regular header of the theme. I can paste the entire changed header file into the template, but I don't think that is the correct way. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: The correct way is to add into your `header.php` file, conditionals that will check if the page you're on is the custom template one, and load it's own menu, and whatever you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create the header file for every template, for example, to call header-blog.php: 
you need to get_header('blo');

Comment: for example, to call header-blog.php: you need to get_header('blog');

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest only replacing the content in the header-file based on the template.
You can therefore add a block just for the template "about.php" like this:

```
if(is_page_template( 'templates/about.php' ) {
    //custom header for about.php

} else {
    //Header for all other pages

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just create a different header file in you current theme 
just like header-custom.php

This example will include header-custom.php

```
<?php
get_header('custom');
?>
```